# Full stack javascript routing explanation needed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've scaffolded a full stack Mongo, Express, Angular, Node app using yeoman with the Angular Fullstack generator

It has created a server/app.js file, which executes a routes.js to handle resources being served by the express server.

The meat of routes.js looks like this:

```
  // Insert routes below
  app.use('/api/things', require('./api/thing'));
  app.use('/api/users', require('./api/user'));

  app.use('/auth', require('./auth'));

  // All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
  app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
   .get(errors[404]);

  // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
  app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
    });
```

My question is how any file other than index.html gets served to the browser. I've tested, and for example the file "http://localhost:9000/assets/images/yeoman.png" does get returned to the browser. But how? From what I am reading in the routes.js, a request to that png *should* return the text of index.html

I'm a bit confused by this and would really appreciate an explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into *config/express.js* you will see something like this:

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));
```

Which should be self-explanatory.

**UPD.** With routes you can overwrite this behaviour for specific files (if you really need it).

Comment: Thanks, the config/express.js file is the piece of the puzzle that I was missing. Makes sense now :-)